# Can't install Ruby 1.9.3 on Mountain Lion with rvm; Homebrew can't find libksba library

Tags: ruby, rvm, osx-mountain-lion, homebrew

I can't get rvm to install Ruby 1.9.3; it keeps on asking for the Homebrew library 'libksba' even though it is already downloaded and installed. When I run the 'brew list' command it shows clearly.

I also have Xcode 4.5 installed.

Is this an environmental variables configuration issue, and I need to configure the path so that they can see each other? If it is, how do I configure it?

How do Homebrew and rvm work together? I'm not clear about this.

Thank you.

```
rvm install 1.9.3






















Ruby (and needed base gems) for your selection will be installed shortly.
Before it happens, please read and execute the instructions below.
Please use a separate terminal to execute any additional commands.

  Notes for Mac OS X 10.8.2, Xcode 4.5.2.

For JRuby:  Install the JDK. See http://developer.apple.com/java/download/  # Current Java version "1.6.0_26"
For IronRuby: Install Mono >= 2.6
For Ruby 1.9.3: Install libksba # If using Homebrew, 'brew install libksba'
For Opal: Install Nodejs with NPM. See http://nodejs.org/download/

To use an RVM installed Ruby as default, instead of the system ruby:

    rvm install 1.8.7 # installs patch 357: closest supported version
    rvm system ; rvm gemset export system.gems ; rvm 1.8.7 ; rvm gemset import system.gems # migrate your gems
    rvm alias create default 1.8.7

And reopen your terminal windows.

Xcode and gcc:

:
```

'brew list' command output

```
brew list
apple-gcc42 automake    libgpg-error    libxml2
autoconf    git     libksba     libxslt
```

Most recent session:

brew upgrade libksba
Error: libksba-1.2.0 already installed
$ brew update
Updated Homebrew from 5909e2c6 to 0e0ef31f.
==> New Formulae
globus-toolkit  postgres-xc
==> Updated Formulae
casperjs    cunit       dxflib      mysql-cluster   smake
cdrtools    dvdrtools   ivy     shmcat      webalizer
==> Deleted Formulae
transcode
unknown7cd1c3e98b07:~ pdenlinger$ rvm install 1.9.3

Ruby (and needed base gems) for your selection will be installed shortly.
Before it happens, please read and execute the instructions below.
Please use a separate terminal to execute any additional commands.

Notes for Mac OS X 10.8.2, Xcode 4.5.2.

For JRuby:  Install the JDK. See http://developer.apple.com/java/download/  # Current Java version "1.6.0_26"
For IronRuby: Install Mono >= 2.6
For Ruby 1.9.3: Install libksba # If using Homebrew, 'brew install libksba'
For Opal: Install Nodejs with NPM. See http://nodejs.org/download/

To use an RVM installed Ruby as default, instead of the system ruby:

```
rvm install 1.8.7 # installs patch 357: closest supported version
rvm system ; rvm gemset export system.gems ; rvm 1.8.7 ; rvm gemset import system.gems # migrate your gems
rvm alias create default 1.8.7
```

And reopen your terminal windows.

Xcode and gcc:

:

Added C compiler error:

```
rvm install 1.9.3
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p362.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Installing Ruby from source to: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p362 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p362, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.9.3-p362 - #extracted to /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p362 (already extracted)
ruby-1.9.3-p362 - #configuring
Error running 'env LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include ./configure --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --prefix=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/rvm/usr', please read /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p362/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
$ cat /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p362/configure.log
[2013-01-01 20:20:35] env LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include ./configure --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --prefix=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/rvm/usr
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.1
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.1
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.1
checking for C compiler default output file name... 
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
```

Environmental variable flags:

```
$ brew update
Already up-to-date.
$ brew tap homebrew/dupes
Error: Already tapped!
$ brew install autoconf automake apple-gcc42
Error: autoconf-2.69 already installed
Error: automake-1.12.6 already installed
Error: apple-gcc42-4.2.1-5666.3 already installed
$ rvm pkg install openssl
Fetching openssl-1.0.1c.tar.gz to /usr/local/rvm/archives
Extracting openssl to /usr/local/rvm/src/openssl-1.0.1c
Configuring openssl in /usr/local/rvm/src/openssl-1.0.1c.
Compiling openssl in /usr/local/rvm/src/openssl-1.0.1c.
Installing openssl to /usr/local/rvm/usr

Please note that it's required to reinstall all rubies:

    rvm reinstall all --force

Updating openssl certificates
$ rvm reinstall all --force
$ rvm install 1.9.3
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p362.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Installing Ruby from source to: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p362 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p362, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.9.3-p362 - #extracted to /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p362 (already extracted)
ruby-1.9.3-p362 - #configuring
Error running 'env LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include ./configure --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --prefix=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/rvm/usr', please read /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p362/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
unknown7cd1c3e98b07:~ pdenlinger$ cat /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p362/configure.log
[2013-01-02 09:58:08] env LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include ./configure --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --prefix=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/rvm/usr
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.1
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.1
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.1
checking for C compiler default output file name... 
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
$ cat config.log
cat: config.log: No such file or directory
$
```

Comment: how is rvm asking you? can you show the output?

Comment: Yes, I have pasted in the output from the rvm and brew commands in an edit above. Thank you.

Comment: `brew update && brew upgrade libksba` maybe?

Comment: Ran 'brew update' and 'brew upgrade libksba'. Show that libksba is running at 1.2.0 (current version).

Answer (score 2):

What you see is output of `rvm requirements` it is show using `less` => use up/down arrows to navigate and `q` to quit less and continue installation.

The requirements are shown only first time you install ruby.

It was a bug and the broken code is already fixed https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/commit/848ef50f1b32c87e853f21e801f167a39e8c9c66

Comment: How to fix this? Entered the 'rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p362' command and it still displayed rvm requirements. I am still using the Mac's system ruby (1.8.7) and can't install 1.9.3. Very frustrating. Thank you.

Comment: start with updating RVM `rvm get head`, then make sure you read my instructions to use keyboard arrows to navigate and `q` to exit the `less` program.

Comment: Thank you. Followed your instructions re less, used q to quit, added "rvm install 1.9.3" command, then got error message that C complier could not compile executables. Detailed error message added to edit above.

Comment: you missed to first read the whole instruction (by using arrows), it explains the requirement of proper compiler and how to get it.

Comment: I went through the less shell and tried to use the arrows, but it didn't show any action for me. Maybe I don't know how to use it, but it just makes no sense to me. I have followed all the instructions about using brew, installed SSL, but I still can't get it to work. Since I am not on the rvm team, I just can't understand what's going on. Where can I get instructions in simple English which even I can understand?

Comment: the instructions are simply `rvm requirements` run it, read it - especially the `gcc-4.2` part.